# How to center a caption if it fits in one single line with the ruled style of the float package after the caption package is loaded?

Tags: floats, captions

I expect under the `ruled` style of the `float` package **center a caption if it fits in one single line and typesets the caption as a normal paragraph in multi lines**, which conforms to the default style in the `article` document class.

By looking at the source code of the `float` package, I found that the style of `ruled` is a natural paragraph. The style of `plain` center a caption if it fits in one single line and typesets the caption as a normal paragraph in multi lines, so I set the caption style of `ruled` to be consistent with `plain`. Here are the corresponding code and result. This is the effect I want.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{xxx}{htbp}{lox}

\makeatletter
\let\floatc@ruled\floatc@plain
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{xxx}
\caption{title}
aaaa
\end{xxx}

\begin{xxx}
\caption{title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title}
aaaa
\end{xxx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I loaded the `caption` package because I need to set the styles of other captions. However, after the `caption` is loaded, caption is always in left. Here are the corresponding code and result.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{xxx}{htbp}{lox}

\makeatletter
\let\floatc@ruled\floatc@plain
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{xxx}
\caption{title}
aaaa
\end{xxx}

\begin{xxx}
\caption{title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title}
aaaa
\end{xxx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I made some attempts, and I found that `boxed` style can center a caption if it fits in one single line when loading `caption` package. Therefore, I guess `caption` has done some special treatment to the `ruled` style, but I can't find any specific treatment at present. Here are the corresponding code and result.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\newfloat{xxx}{htbp}{lox}

\begin{document}

\begin{xxx}
\caption{title}
aaaa
\end{xxx}

\begin{xxx}
\caption{title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title}
aaaa
\end{xxx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I searched the source code of `caption` package and found `\DeclareCaptionStyle{ruled}{labelfont=bf,labelsep=space,strut=0}` in line 921 of `caption.sty`. If I change it to `\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,labelsep=space,strut=0}`. I found `singlelinecheck` is working.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
% In line 921, change
% \DeclareCaptionStyle{ruled}{labelfont=bf,labelsep=space,strut=0}
% to
% \captionsetup{labelfont=bf,labelsep=space,strut=0}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=true}

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{xxx}{htbp}{lox}

\makeatletter
\let\floatc@ruled\floatc@plain
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{xxx}
\caption{title}
aaaa
\end{xxx}

\begin{xxx}
\caption{title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title}
aaaa
\end{xxx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To sum up, how to make the float of `ruled` style center a caption if it fits in one single line when the `caption` package is loaded.

Comment: It seems you ansered your own question.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you. I'm sure I've found the right direction after getting your affirmation. I'm curious what `\DeclareCaptionStyle` did. Did it set `slc=0`? I didn't find the answer in the definition of `\DeclareCaptionStyle` in `caption3.sty`.

Comment: BTW, I experimented and am sure caption actually modifies some of the float source code `\AtBeginDocument` in order to replace float's custom caption while still putting the caption outside the box.  For example, once caption is loaded, `\let\floatc@ruled\floatc@plain` does nothing.

Comment: @JohnKormylo You are right. If `caption` is loaded, `\let\floatc@ruled\floatc@plain` does nothing. I found that loading the `ruled` option can avoid `caption` from modifying the `ruled` style of the `float` package. I have answered this question myself, hoping to help others with the same confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled]{caption}
\captionsetup[ruled]{singlelinecheck=true}

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{xxx}{htbp}{lox}

\begin{document}

\begin{xxx}
\caption{title}
aaaa
\end{xxx}

\begin{xxx}
\caption{title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title}
aaaa
\end{xxx}

\end{document}
```

[image]